# Filter pandas Dataframe on Javascript Website

Tags: javascript, python, html, pandas, flask

I have 'inherited' a larger software project using python/flask in the backend and HTML/Javascript in the frontend. I now want to implement some interactiveness on one of the websites.
I successfully passed a dataframe to the webpage and can display its content. I have some filters as buttons to change in between various views. I can access those filter values within the webpage itself. How can I now pass these new values to the dataframe to filter it without having to re-render the whole page?
Please note that I use template.render() instead of render_templates() as the project does not have a templates folder and it would require too much restructuring to change this.
This is the relevant python part:

```
@app.route('/tagging/OverviewPerDoc.html')
def analysis():
    x = <function which returns a pandas dataframe>()
    tempid = globalxmlid
    datatuple = [x, tempid]
    filetoopen = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), config.filepaths.overviewperdoc)

    with open(filetoopen) as fi:
        template = Template(fi.read())
    return template.render(data = datatuple)
```

This is the website part:

```html
<body>
(...)
<button id="magicbutton" class="btn btn-primary my-group-button" type="submit" style="margin-right:5px;" value = "Show">Show</button>
    (...)
    {% block content %}
         (...)
        </div> <br> <br> <br>
         <h1 align="center">{{data[0][data[0]['identifier'] == data[1]]['Name'].iloc[0]}}</h1>
   (...)
   <div class="container">
                        <table>
                      <tr>
                        <th></th>
  (...)
                        <tr>
                        <td>Value</td>
                        <td>{{data[0][data[0]['identifier'] == data[1]]['Value'].iloc[0]}} {{data[0][data[0]['identifier'] == data[1]]['currency'].iloc[0]}}</td>
                        <td>100%</td>
                      </tr>
       (...)
```

When clicking on my test button, I can print its value to the console.

```html
<script>
    function magicfunction()
    {
        var test = savethecurrentxml;
        console.log(test);
 }
</script>
```

As I said, all of this is working I now just want to change it to something like:

```
data[0][data[0]['identifier'] == test]['Name'].iloc[0]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a separate API endpoint that would return just the filtered dataframe, and have Javascript query the endpoint and use the response to modify your page.

Comment: Ok, but that would mean to re-render the whole page where the result will only show up if I reload it?
I need something like 'return jsonify(mydataframe)' that is then instantly renderer on my website without reloading it...

Comment: Oh wait....I think I get what you are suggesting. Although I need to figure out how to do that.
But thanks, it still helped me to 'find the right track'